# Sending String From JavaScript to Servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I know this is a heavily asked question, but no matter how much I google it, I still can't seem to work.

I simply want to send several parameters to a servlet, `"/gamesave"`.

The way I'm currently trying to do this is by clicking a button which calls this `saveFunction()` and then another button to actually redirect to the servlet.

It's pretty ghetto, but just trying to test this functionality.

Can anyone help me get this working? Do I need to import anything special to use the jquery?

```
var selection = "Happy";

$.ajax({
    url: '/gamesave',
    data: { stringParameter: selection },
    type: 'POST'
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. [Open your web console](https://www.google.com.co/search?q=open%20web%20console%20chrome).
2. Read the message in console tab, the last one.
3. If there is a message saying that $ is not defined, then add jQuery to your HTML file:

   ```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
   ```

That's downloading jQuery from the internet when you load your page, or you can download that and put it with a local path:

```
<script src="/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="some/directory/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

If you need to understand what to put in `src` check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I added the first script line to download jquery. I'm still getting null when I try to get the value in the servlet. I'm pulling it like this                                     String output = req.getParameter("stringParameter");                                         Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: I have not used servlets a long time ago, does your server has some log you can see what parameters are being sent, you could google that, or, check your browser console, to make sure the ajax request is being triggered, it would help, but anyway you will ned to confirm that params are in server.

Comment: I don't think the parameters are being sent at all. If I changed my method and simply set a button's text to what I want to send, is there a way for me to simply send the button's text to the servlet?